# Заметные задержки у websocket(soket io) если оба клиента висят на одном белом ip

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, websocket, socket.io

Для меня это не очень критично но все же интересно почему так.
У меня есть сервер с ip андесом "A" и 2 клиента с белым ip "B". В этом случае качество соединения отвратительное... один запрос может идти до 10 и более секунд. но если у одного из клиентов поменять ip на "C" то все начинает летать... запросы отправляются и приходят очень быстро.

Такое ощущение что когда 2 клиента на одном ip сервер отправляет запрос но он теряется и он его отправляет пока юзер не словит его. Есть у кого-то варианты какие то ?

Cо стороны сервера nginx + node + socket io
Клиент React + socket io

Буду благодарен если кто-то объяснит причину этому беспределу =)

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что когда качество связи отвратительное,то при тестировании обаклиента -это просто две вкладки в одном и том же браузере на одном и том же компе? Просто хочется методомисключения понять, в чем можетбыть проблема. как  варианты: запустить клиентовв разных браузерах. И еще - на разных компах, но под одним (внешним) ip.

Comment: нет, телефон и ПК на одном wifi который имеет белый ip. На ПК 2-3-4 вкладки работают шустро как и телефон на LTE вместо Wifi